# Coq adding a new variable instead of using the correct one

Tags: coq

I'm working on my own implementation of vectors in Coq, and I'm running into a bizarre problem.

Here is my code thus far:

```
Inductive Fin : nat -> Type :=
  |FZ : forall n, Fin (S n)
  |FS : forall n, Fin n -> Fin (S n).

Definition emptyf(A : Type) : Fin 0 -> A.
  intro e; inversion e.
Defined.

Inductive Vec(A : Type) : nat -> Type :=
  |Nil  : Vec A 0
  |Cons : forall n, A -> Vec A n -> Vec A (S n).

Definition head(A : Type)(n : nat)(v : Vec A (S n)) : A :=
  match v with
  |Cons a _ => a
  end.

Definition tail(A : Type)(n : nat)(v : Vec A (S n)) : Vec A n :=
  match v with
  |Cons _ w => w
  end.

Fixpoint index(A : Type)(n : nat) : Vec A n -> Fin n -> A :=
  match n as n return Vec A n -> Fin n -> A with
  |0   => fun _ i => emptyf _ i
  |S m => fun v i => match i with
                     |FZ _ => head v
                     |FS j => index (tail v) j
                     end
  end.
```

Everything up to `tail` compiles fine, but when I try to compile `index`, I receive the following error:

```
Error:
In environment
index : forall (A : Type) (n : nat), Vec A n -> Fin n -> A
A : Type
n : nat
m : nat
v : Vec A (S m)
i : Fin (S m)
n0 : nat
j : Fin n0
The term "j" has type "Fin n0" while it is expected to have type "Fin m".
```

Clearly, the culprit is that Coq introduces the new variable `n0` instead of assigning `j` the type `Fin m`, even though this is the only possible type for `j` which would result in `i` being built from `j`.  Any idea why this would happen, and how I might be able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find `Vec` and `Fin` very hard to use in general, so I these days I use `'I_n` and `n.-tuples T` from math-comp, which are just naturals and lists with an irrelevant proof attached. However, if you want to continue the fun of complex pattern matches, you could try to define a stronger pattern matching principle:

```
Definition fin_case T m (i : Fin m) : T -> (Fin (pred m) -> T) -> T :=
  match i with
  | FZ _   => fun fn fz => fn
  | FS _ j => fun fn fz => fz j
  end.
```

Once you have `fin_case`, you function definition works:

```
Fixpoint index (A : Type) (n : nat) : Vec A n -> Fin n -> A :=
  match n as n return Vec A n -> Fin n -> A with
  | 0   => fun _ i => emptyf _ i
  | S m => fun v i => fin_case i (head v) (index (tail v))
  end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but It seems to me like this just pushes the problem onto how to define `fin_case`. No matter what I try, I still run into the same problem. Would you mind sharing the definition you have in mind?

Comment: Updated, a couple of comments: a) Note that this "pushing the problem onto" is indeed more than that and a crucial tool in Coq style dependent programming. b) There are many other ways to solve these kind of problems, indeed, writing a proper match still feels like a bit of an art.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you do not need to pattern-match against `n`, but only against the argument of type `Fin n`. The resulting definition is simpler.

```
Fixpoint index {A:Type} {n:nat} (i:Fin n) : Vec A n -> A :=
  match i in Fin n0 return Vec A n0 -> A with
  | FZ => fun v => head v
  | FS j => fun v => index j (tail v)
  end.
```

Coq is actually cleaver enough to guess the annotations.

```
Fixpoint index {A:Type} {n:nat} (i:Fin n) : Vec A n -> A :=
  match i with
  | FZ => fun v => head v
  | FS j => fun v => index j (tail v)
  end.
```

Comment: This one feels like magic -- simple argument swapping solves the problem instantaneously. Nice!

Comment: I did not realize that I switched the arguments. Another difference with the original function: the decreasing argument is `i`, not `n`.

Comment: Yes, however if you start with pattern-mathing on a vector (as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39469676/2747511)), you will have to use something like the convoy pattern (see [larsr's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39467904/2747511)). So that swap is actually a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `match` you can lose information. I used the [convoy pattern](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html) to get the info back into the context.

```
    match i in Fin (S n0) return n0 = m  -> A with 
      ... => fun H : n0 = m => ...
    end  eq_refl
```

enables Coq to get the info `n0 = m` into the context.  It is sent into the match clauses as a function parameter.  To use it in the type check I use `(match H with ... end)` so that Coq understands that `Fin n0 = Fin m`.
This is the solution.

```
Fixpoint index(A : Type)(n : nat) : Vec A n -> Fin n -> A :=

  match n as n return Vec A n -> Fin n -> A with
  |0   => fun _ i => emptyf _ i
  |S m => fun v i =>
           match i in Fin (S n') return n' = m  -> A with
             |FZ _ => fun _ => head _ _ v
             |FS _ j => fun H => index (tail v) (match H with eq_refl _  => j end)
           end eq_refl
  end.
```

When the type checking doesn't understand that two things are equal, usually the convoy pattern can help you get that info into the context.  I also recommend using `refine` to incrementally build up the term.  It  let's you see what information there is in the context.

Comment: A simple `Definition cast (m n : nat) (i : Fin m) (H : m = n) : Fin n := eq_rec m Fin i n H.` might make the code a bit easier to read (`(match H with eq_refl _  => j end)` gets replaced by `(cast j H)`).

Comment: A comment on the solutions using equality casts, (including the one with inversion) is that they may not compute/reduce properly inside Coq, needing additional rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the other answers, a tactic-based solution:

```
Fixpoint index (A : Type) (n : nat) (v : Vec A n) (i : Fin n) : A.
  destruct v as [| n h tl].
  - exact (emptyf A i).
  - inversion i as [ | ? i'].
    + exact h.
    + exact (index _ _ tl i').
Defined.
```

The `inversion` tactic takes care of the "information loss". If you try to `Print index.` the result won't be pretty, but Coq essentially uses the convoy pattern @larsr has mentioned.

Notice that this approach doesn't use pattern-matching on `n`. It pattern-matches on the vector argument instead, that's why it doesn't need the `head` and `tail` functions.